# TYPO3 - Markup using Math

Tags: typo3, typoscript

So lets say I have something like this:

```
20 = CONTENT
20{
    table = tt_content
    select{
        pidInList = 1
        where = colPos = 0
    }

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj{

        wrap = <div class="normal">|</div>

        10 = TEXT
        10{
            field = bodytext
        }
    }
}
```

and I want that every third object changes the class "normal" by "special". How could I do such operation in Typoscript?

Comment: You have to use typoscript registers for that. I don't have a typo3 installation available here, do I can't tell you more.

Comment: I figured its something like that, but I dont know exactly how :(

Comment: Search for something like  `typoscript register zebra` in g**gle. Maybe you find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [optionSplit](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/optionSplit) ([DE](http://wiki.typo3.org/De%3aTSref/optionSplit)) for this task on the `wrap` value, you need `abcabc` pattern  where `a,b = normal`, `c = special`, so most probably it will be something like this:

```
wrap = a||b||c |*| a||b||c
```

Wrote it from top of my head so you need to check it.

Comment: I wrote this: 20.renderObj.wrap = a|| |*| b|| |*| c||  but all I see are "a" at the beginning of every entry. Am I writing it in the wrong place?

Comment: `|*|` splits 3 main parts: begin, middle, end. but in each you can use additional splitting with `||` so it can be: `a||b||c||d||..||z`, but spliting single item with `a||` doesn't make any sense